# Is there a way to test android applications directly on phone, without the emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I test applications in eclipse without the emulator ? I have a phone with android, and I want to test the apps directly on phone.

**Update:** I want to develop the entire application using the phone. I hate the emulator because it's very slow on my computer. Also, my application needs GPS and I can better handle this using the phone.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, Android explicitly supports this. Try this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Answer (score 2):

Connect your phone by USB cable to your computer.  Remember to set android:debuggable="true" in your application in the AndroidManifest file.

ETA: alternatively, you can email the .apk files to an email account the phone can access and install from there.  You'll also need "unknown sources" ticked under Settings -> Application. (Although that will only let you run them, not debug them.)

Comment: If you decide to go down this route (rather than the far simpler route of connecting the phone to the pc via USB) you could get an app such as `estrong file explorer` and install your .apk over a LAN.

Comment: don't forget to set debuggable to false before release. if you're using eclipse it is not necessary to set the flag.

Answer (score 1):

Yea you need to add the "charge" usb drivers then in the settings turn on USB debugging. I would check with "adb logcat" if you see the logs start to roll your set. In eclipse just build and if everything is setup correct it will install and start on your device. If you have more than one device attached it will ask you to pick.

Comment: yes ben is correct, dont forget to add android:debuggable="true"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but in addition to what others mentioned, you need to install a device driver for the particular Android device that you are connecting through USB. Each Android phone may require a different driver (at least on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

there are a few thinks you need to do:

1. setup as others have said, with SDK / eclipse / etc
2. on your phone configure it to be debugging.  Settings -> Applications -> Developement
3. make sure you have the USB driver for your phone

During setup of the SDK there is a weird Java setup gotcha.  I found great walk through at http://www.mobiusbay.com/home/android%E2%80%93day0gettingstarted

Short story, if you have the Java SDK installed and the Android SDK claims you do not.  Hit the back button and then the Next button.

At the walk through they show a simple application to verify it is running.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can without the emulator, but not without the Android SDK/Eclipse (at least, not that I know of).  You do it by attaching your Android device and then going into "Debug Configurations" (Debug drop-down menu).  In there you should be able to add your device as a target.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its very simple actually. In case of Samsung devices all you need is "Kies". Follow the link to [download for either Windows or Mac OS](http://www.samsungapps.com/mercury/about/onPc.as?COUNTRY_CODE=IND&_isAppsDep=Y).

Once the download is complete, install the application.

Next make sure that the following are enable/checked on the device and the emulator:

Device:

1. Enable USB Debugging
2. Enable `Stay Awake`

Emulator:

1. Within the `AndroidManifest.xml`, set Debugging to `True`

Once the above mentioned steps are completed, connect the device to your PC and click <kbd>Run as Android Application</kbd>

Now you should see the application running on your device.