# how to test My mobileApp on mobile phone?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on eclipse(android) for developing mobile apps,and
I don't like the virtual emulator on the computer, so I would like to know
How can I test my App using my mobile?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are a few thinks you need to do:

1. setup with SDK / eclipse / etc
2. on your phone configure it to be debugging. Settings -> Applications
   ->Developement
3. make sure you have the USB driver for your phone

also read [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) ...

and last but not least possible duplicate of  [Is there a way to test android applications directly on phone, without the emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807503/is-there-a-way-to-test-android-applications-directly-on-phone-without-the-emula)

Comment: as the guy above stated plus that if you have the drivers installed on your computer you can go into run configuration>target> select always prompt for device and if your device is connected you can select your device to run directly..